# I am constructing my own language and I need one more consonant

Tags: phonology, phonetics

Other than BCChDDz FGHJK LLyMNNy PRSShT VYZZh.
C is Ts, Ch is as in China, Dz is Italian soft J/G, J is Dy/Dj/DZh.
W is too similar to V and U.
Dh is too similar to D and Th to T,
and I find it funny how the Catalans pronounce Barcelona.
It sounds like they are lisping and can't pronounce their C/S.
Please no popping/explosive, tonal, guttural
or too similar soft or hard version of existing one,
and Loh and Loch sound exactly the same, to me,
so no Esperanto's guttural H.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me write down the consonants in a more rational way:

```
P  B  F  V  M
T  D  S  Z  N  C      L  R
      Sh Zh    Ch  Dz/J
         Y  Ny        Ly
K  G  H
```

from the sketchy description in the question I don't get the difference between J and Dz.

The system has some obvious gaps in the last row: You could easily fill in a voiced counterpart to H as Gh (the sound of Spanish G in many situations (in the middle of words before a, o, or u, and not after an n, like in *amigo*) or Ng, the nasal counterpart of G, as a consonant of its own right.

Other easy additions may be further affricates, like Pf as segment filling the place above C, or a true Dz (D+Z) as voiced counterpart of C.

Or Add Ç (the German *Ich-Laut*, or the initial sound in some pronunciations of the English word *huge*) as voiceless counterpart to Y.

Any of these choices are quite natural and would not add anything exotic to the sound system of your conlang.

Comment: In the end of the day, you construct your language according to your taste. So take my suggestions as what hey are: just suggestions. You are free to not follow any of them, and it will not offend me.

Comment: Spanish g before e & i is /x/, a _voiceless_ velar fricative. Spanish g is a voiced fricative before any other vowel and not word-initially or after n.

Comment: @SirCornflakes the correction was still wrong, just in a different way. I've corrected it properly now

Comment: What is the difference between the initial consonants of *jump* and *gentle*??  International Phonetic Alphabet would help.

Answer (score 2):

@SirCornflakes gives a more structured answer, but here are some more consonants to consider.

You only have one R. There are many sounds in different languages that are written as R. Which one do you mean? Why not use both rolling R, as in Spanish, along with French R or American R? Mixing of different R-sounds occur, for instance, in some [Swedish dialects](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6taregeln)(Can't find any english language description, but maybe you could run it through a translator?)

Otherwise, you can never go wrong with a [voiced retroflex flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_flap)!

Finally, if you want something more exotic you could check out the [sj-sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sj-sound)! It's mainly used in Swedish (No, I'm not biased towards that language at all...) and Wikipedia says:

> These sounds are transcribed ⟨ɧ⟩ in the International Phonetic Alphabet. The International Phonetic Association (IPA) describes them as "simultaneous [ʃ] and [x]", but this realization is not attested, and phoneticians doubt that such a realization actually occurs in any language.

Because it's so rare, only found in Swedish, a German dialect and maybe some Himalayan language, there is some debate on how it's actually best described, but don't let that stop you.